# Let $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be ${\cal C}^1$, such that $|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ ||x − y||^2$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb R^2$. Show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be ${\cal C}^1$, such that  $|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ ||x − y||^2$ for all $x,y\in  \Bbb R^2$. Show that $f$ is constant.

I'm not sure about :

$=> \lim_{x\to y} \frac{|f(x) − f(y)|}
{\|x − y\|}  \le  \lim_{x\to y}\|x − y\|$

$=> |f '(x)| \le 0$

Is it true or not ?

Comment: why do you think that it's not true ?

Comment: Why do you use (single) $|$ for the LHS and (double) $||$ for the RHS?

Comment: @Surb Because i think it's not possible to generalize that lim_x->0 (f(x + h) − f(x))/h =f'(x) in this case

Comment: @VIVID The LHS is the absolute value of a real number, while the right hand side is the magnitude of a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Having the notation keep track of what dimensional objects are in the expression can sometimes be helpful.

Comment: @ndhanson3 When I wrote that comment it was $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. It seems they edited it.

Answer (score 3):

Select $y=x+\lambda \hat{v}\in \mathbb{R}^m$, where $\hat v$ is a unit norm vector. Now note that with $f\in\mathbb{R^n}$

$$\lim_{\lambda\to 0}\frac{||f(x+\lambda \hat{v})-f(x)||}{|\lambda|}=||\left(\hat{v}\cdot \nabla\right)f||\leq\lim_{\lambda\to0}||\lambda||=0$$
and therefore we conclude that for any unit vector $ \hat v$
$$||\left(\hat{v}\cdot \nabla\right)f||=0\iff\left(\hat{v}\cdot \nabla\right)f=0$$
Choosing $\hat v=\hat x_1, \hat x_2,..., \hat x_m$ we find
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=...=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}=0$$
from which it is evident that $f$ can only be a constant vector in order to satisfy this inequality.

For the problem statement simply restrict $m=2, n=1$, but the nature of the arguments remains the same.

Comment: Good answer for the restricted problem statement.

Comment: This can be readily extended to any function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ since none of the arguments depend on dimensionality. That being said, answering exactly what the question asks is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Good answer in all respects, then. The comment was in part a reaction to the OP changing the question as I worked on it.

Comment: I knew it could be generalized so I didn't bother changing anything. The original intention was to prove $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, which is why I'm using the wording "vector" in the last sentence. Thanks for alerting me to it!

Answer (score 1):

This is true more generally for $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ where $m \geqslant 1$.

Since $f \in C^1$ , for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $\delta> 0$ such that if $0 < \|h \| < \delta$, then

$$\| f(x+h) - f(x) - Df(x) \cdot h\| < \epsilon\|h\|$$

By the reverse triangle inequality,

$$\|Df(x) \cdot h\| \leqslant \|f(x+h) - f(x)\| + \epsilon \|h\| \leqslant \|h\|^2 + \epsilon \|h\|$$

For any partial derivative $D_jf_i(x)$ where $1 \leqslant j \leqslant n$ and $1 \leqslant i \leqslant m$, we have

$$ |D_jf_i(x)| |h_j|\leqslant \|Df(x) \cdot h\|\leqslant \|h\|^2 + \epsilon\|h\|  $$

and, in particular for $h = (0, \ldots, h_j, \ldots 0)$ where $0 < h_j < \delta$,

$$ |D_jf_i(x)||h_j| \leqslant |h_j|^2 + \epsilon|h_j|  $$

Thus,

$$|D_jf_i(x)| \leqslant \lim_{\|h\| \to 0}(|h_j|+ \epsilon) = \epsilon$$

Since this holds for all $\epsilon >0$, the partial derivatives are zero and $f$ is constant.